# change from julia mode to shell mode

Tags: julia

I am using Julia 1.4.2. my version info is,

Julia Version 1.4.2
Commit 44fa15b150* (2020-05-23 18:35 UTC)
Platform Info:
OS: Linux (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz
WORD_SIZE: 64
LIBM: libopenlibm
LLVM: libLLVM-8.0.1 (ORCJIT, skylake)

How to change from Julia command mode to Shell mode in julia?

I want to perform os commands such as `ls` `pwd` etc.,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use semicolon (;). You can read about different shell modes [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/REPL/#The-different-prompt-modes-1).

Answer (score 4):

Like the other answer say you use the semicolon `;`.

Note that shell mode (contrary to the package manage mode) is not sticky - that is whenever you execute command you are back in Julia REPL. Sometimes when I want to execute many command line command a good workflow is to type `;bash` (or `;cmd` on Windows), do all your stuff and then come back to Julia by executing `exit` - this works quite well and I found it to be most convenient.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that in Windows Powershell going to shell requires the following sequence:

1. Type: ;

This goes to Julia shell. DOS commands not working.

2. Type: cmd
   Now you are in the DOS-shell

To get back to Julia:

1. Type: exit
2. Type: Ctrl+c (Hold down Ctrl button AND press c)